# Bloquear eventos com jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou há algum tempo vasculhando a documentação do jquery em busca de uma função com o seguinte comportamento

Suponhamos que temos dois botoes na tela cada um com um evento de click diferente:

```
<button>Effetc1</button>
<button>Effetc2</button>
<div> Click in first button to change</div>
```

O primeiro dispara uma animação, já o segundo lança alerta. Eu quero que o evento do segundo botão aguarde até a conclusão do primeiro.

Porém são dois eventos separados, então não dá para sobrepor callbacks, eu quero que durante a execução do primeiro evento, nenhum outro evento seja executado a até a conclusão do primeiro. Exemplo abaixo

http://jsfiddle.net/xwky0wc1/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vezes um simples `fleg` pode resolver o seu problema.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fleg = false;
  $('button:eq(0)').click(function() {
    $('div').html('click in second button during animation');
    $('div').animate({
      width: 300
    }, 5000, function() {
      $('div').animate({
        lineHeight: 100
      }, 5000, function() {
        fleg = true;
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
  $('button:eq(1)').click(function() {
    if (fleg) {
      alert('Shit, stoped animation... Wait to finish idiot jquery');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Effetc1</button>
<button>Effetc2</button>
<div>Click in first button to change</div>
```

Uma função que faça isso em `jquery` eu nunca vi, mas você pode aguardar o termino do animate colocando uma `function(){}` e colocar o fleg verdadeiro para poder acionar o botão.